# Block of chars in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, binary

INPUT Example:

1010111

111100000

11000111

Is there any built in method in python to check if as an INPUT I have 2 blocks of chars: 0 and 1. What I mean:

1010111  -> FALSE

111100000 -> TRUE

11000111 -> FALSE

'0' are on the one side and '1' are on the another site.

Comment: Please post the code you have used to try and solve your problem.

Comment: I was tempted to vote-to-close as unclear, but actually the question is very clear. The short answer is "no" ... and so is the long answer (below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not.

Your requirement is extremely specific and narrow. Builtin functions usually implement very generic requirements that come up time and again.

You will need to build your specific solution using a number of built in functions and general expressions.

Now the generic problem you are trying to solve is writing an acceptor, or recognizer, which is a type of automata (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Acceptors_and_recognizers). There may be libraries for Python out there which will let you do it - but nothing built in.